# Can't send large json for AJAX responce from PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax

I try to get a large data from mongoDB, but it returned broken on the midle, like `[item, item, ite` .
When i request smaller data everyfing is ok.
Code in php file:

```
if ($location) {
  //define cursor
  $rest = $collection->find(['borough' => $location]);
  //make array of restaurants names
  foreach ($rest as $restaurant) {
    if ($restaurant['name'] != '') {
      $array[] = $restaurant['name'];
    }
  }
  //forming response
  if ($array) {
    echo json_encode(
      $array,
      JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP
    );
  }
  else {
    http_response_code(204);
  }
  exit();
}
```

Getting " SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 65528 " when i parse it in JS, and allways same position no matter what is a data. This is probably php problem, because if JSON make from `$array=range(1,1000000)` i give a same result. Any idea?

upd: sorry, coppied wrong section of code. Edited.

Comment: Would you not want to do the encode on the array, once, _after_ the foreach is done?

Comment: Are you sure you want the ` if ($array)` block inside the loop?

Comment: sorry, it be a wrong variant of code.

Comment: This must be related to your web software (Apache or Nginx) limiting the response size.